# jQuery Google map page to get current location

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a VF page that displays a map based on the coords passed to it from my custom object record, this all works fine. I'm now trying to add it to my SF1 mobile app and use the users current location rather than the record coords.

The findLocation function is getting the correct coords, however, they are null when i try to use them in the initGMap function, im presuming because the initGMap has continued to execute before findLocation has had a chance to return the coords??

Appreciate any thoughts on what im missing, trimmed code below:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false"  standardStylesheets="false" cache="false" doctype="html-5.0" controller="MapController">
```

Nearby Stores

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>

<!-- jQuery + jQuery Mobile files -->
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'jquery-1.8.3.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js')}"/>
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jquery, 'jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css')}" />  

<!-- Google Maps -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

<style>
    body, html {
        height: 100%;   
        width: 100%;
    }
    #nearbyStoresPage, .ui-content, #map_canvas { 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 100%; 
        padding: 0; 
    }
</style>

<script>
    var map;
    var lat = {!store.Location__Latitude__s};
    var lng = {!store.Location__Longitude__s};
    //var lat = {!Latitude};
    //var lng = {!Longitude};
    var storeName = "{!store.Name}";
    var fascia = "{!store.Fascia__c}";
    var siteLat = {!site.Location__Latitude__s};
    var siteLng = {!site.Location__Longitude__s};
    var siteName = "{!site.Name}";
    var status = "{!site.Status__c}";
    var siteLink = "{!site.Id}";
    var curMode = "{!mode}";
    var mobLAT = 51.45;
    var mobLONG = -0.145;
    //$j = jQuery.noConflict();

    $('#nearbyStoresPage').live('pageshow', function() {

        initGmap();

    });


    function initGmap() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(siteLat, siteLng);
        var mapOptions;
         findLocation();
        if (curMode == "store")
        {
             mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                zoom: 13,

                // The following options are added to optimize for mobile screens. 
                mapTypeControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false, 
                scaleControl: false,
                rotateControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                }
            };
        }else 
        {

            alert(mobLAT);
             mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(mobLAT, mobLONG),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                zoom: 13,

                // The following options are added to optimize for mobile screens. 
                mapTypeControl: false,
                streetViewControl: false, 
                scaleControl: false,
                rotateControl: false,
                panControl: false,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                }
            };
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

        if(curMode == 'store')
        {
            createMarkerAndInfoWindow(storeName, latlng, fascia);
        }else
        { 
            createSiteMarkerAndInfoWindow(siteName, siteLatLng, status);
        }
    }

    // Find GPS Location
    function findLocation() {
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (
                    // successFunction
                    function(position) {
                        mobLAT = position.coords.latitude;
                        mobLONG = position.coords.longitude;
                        alert(mobLAT);
                        alert(mobLONG);
                    },
                    // errorFunction
                    function(position) {
                        alert("Geolocation not available");
                    }
                );
        } else {
            alert("navigator.geolocation is not available");
        }
    }


    }

    function getNearbyStores() { 
        MapController.getNearbyStores(lat, lng, function (result, event) {
            if (event.status) {
                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var storeName = result[i].Name;
                    var storeFascia = result[i].Fascia__c;
                    var storeLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(result[i].Location__Latitude__s, result[i].Location__Longitude__s);

                    createMarkerAndInfoWindow(storeName, storeLatlng, storeFascia);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    function getNearbySites() { 
        MapController.getNearbySites(lat, lng, function (result, event) {
            if (event.status) {
                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var siteName = result[i].Name;
                    var siteStatus = result[i].Status__c;
                    var siteLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(result[i].Location__Latitude__s, result[i].Location__Longitude__s);
                    var siteLink = result[i].Id;
                    createSiteMarkerAndInfoWindow(siteName, siteLatlng, siteStatus, siteLink);
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

```
        <a href="#" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" onclick="getNearbyStores();">Show Stores</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left" onclick="getNearbySites();">Show Sites</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This sounds like it's mostly a JavaScript problem; you might have better luck on Stack Overflow (after stripping it down to straight HTML and JS)

Comment: You should uncomment and fix your jQuery to use noConflict. Also, consider moving actions and data fetches that need to happen on page load to the ready function to sequence events correctly.

Comment: I guess you're presuming correctly what your issue is. navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is an asynchronous function accepting a callback function as its first parameter. Why don't you put the code part in the else tree - the one starting with "alert (mobLAT);" - into the success function of getCurrentPosition? That will probably solve your problem.